# AngularJS : How to change a value in all items in an ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, angularjs-ng-model

I have a data model that comes in, by default I give the first ticker a selected status of true.

Now when a user clicks another item, I need to efficiently deselect all the others and set the selected value to true for the item clicked:

```
<li class="ticker-li"
    ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
    ng-hide="ticker.removed"
    ng-class="{'selected':ticker.selected}"
    ng-mouseleave="hideTickerOptions()">

    <div class="ticker"
         ng-click="unselectAll(); ticker.selected = !ticker.selected;
                   selectTicker(ticker);">
         {{ticker.ticker}}
    </div>
</li>
```

Tried a `forEach` function here, but with the error `[object Array] is not a function`:

```
var vs = $scope;

vs.unselectAll = function() {
   vs.tickers.forEach(vs.tickers, function(ticker) {
       ticker.selected = false;
   });
};
```

A regular for-loop will work, but is it an efficient way to toggle all the selected values to false?

```
for (var i = 0; i < vs.tickers.length; i++) {
    vs.tickers[i].selected = false;
}
```

My thinking here is run this unselectAll function to deselect everything, then the next code in the markup which select the current item:

```
<div class="ticker"
     ng-click="unselectAll(); ticker.selected = !ticker.selected;
               selectTicker(ticker);">
     {{ticker.ticker}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to do it using radio inputs.

```js
 var app = angular.module('AppForm', []);

app.controller('ctrForm', function ($scope) {

        $scope.choices = [
            { id: 'Choice1', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice2', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice3', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice4', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice5', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice6', check: false },
            { id: 'Choice7', check: false }
        ];

        $scope.setDefault = function (item) {
            angular.forEach($scope.choices, function (p) {
                p.check = false; //set them all to false
            });
            item.check = true; //set the clicked one to true
        };
        
    });
```

```css
.selected {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.21/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="AppForm" ng-controller="ctrForm">
        <ul>
            <li style="list-style:none" ng-class="{'selected':item.check}" ng-repeat="item in choices"><input type="radio" name="group" ng-model="item.check" ng-click="setDefault(item)" value="true" />{{item.id}}...{{item.check}}</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Comment: Nice :) thanks for the working example... I actually went with a `for-loop` but will test this out later to see if there is a performance difference.

Comment: I am sorry, i noted today there were a little bug. If you find a solution tell me. :)

Answer (score 0):

The foreach wouldn't be less efficient than anything angular could do 'for free'. Either way it'll have to set the others as unselected..

What'd I'd propose instead would be to have a single thing "selectedItem" and a set of things "items".

then you can 'say'

```
<li class="ticker-li"
    ng-repeat="ticker in tickers"
    ng-hide="ticker.removed"
    ng-class="{'selected':ticker == selectedTicker}"
    ng-mouseleave="hideTickerOptions()">

    <div class="ticker" ng-click="selectedTicker = ticker">
         {{ticker.ticker}}
    </div>
</li>
```

you could then access selectedTicker to get it's properties

```
<div>{{selectedTicker.name}}</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, this still leaves all the previously selected tickers selected.

Comment: it will leave the selected, but I'm thinking, instead of checking for isSelected, you'll check to see if they're equal to the 'selectedTicker' (see the ng-class tag in my code)

Comment: Yeah that's basically the same thing as what I was using `ng-class="{'selected':ticker.selected}"` Just need a way to update the model to remove or change the `selected` or `selectedTicker` from all the items before reselecting again.

Comment: What I was suggesting was to avoid setting selected for every item.  Instead set a new object to the selected one each time you change the selection.  Then to tell if a ticker is selected you can just check if it's equal to the selected ticker.  That way you don't have to iterate over all tickers when you change your selection.

Answer (score 0):

If your set on using ticker.selected, you can use a jquery .each loop to unselect all of them.

```
$scope.selectTicker = function(ticker)
{
  //deselect all tickers
  $.each(tickers, function() { this.selected = false; });

  //select the ticker you passed in
  ticker.selected = true;
}
```

and in your view:

```
<div class="ticker"ng-click="selectTicker(ticker);">
     {{ticker.ticker}}
</div>
```

Comment: I definitely want to avoid using jQuery, I use to rely on it as a crutch while I was learning Angular. I'm thinking it's starting to look like the `for-loop` is the easiest way to do this.

Comment: When people say not to use jquery with angular they mean don't use jquery's DOM manipulation stuff.  Not that you need to avoid all of JQuery.  Anyways: angular has a foreach that works exactly the same https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach

Comment: Yeah, my thinking though is keep the app as light as possible, so fewest downloads needed for the user. I tried the Angular forEach above, but with errors :(

Comment: I was really into that for a while (keeping it light) but realistically, if you link to a minified jquery source, it's not going to slow the user down in the least compared to them pulling down your actual app from your server.